# Remove consecutive elements given a starting key and an ending key

Tags: php, range, key, filtering, sequential-number

I have an input array with keys representing 24-hour "military" time and values representing 12-hour "am/pm" time.  I want to remove consecutive elements from my array determined by two variables that contain "military" time values.

Here are my input variables:

```
$starttime = '5';
$endtime = '17';
$timings = array(
     '0' => '12AM',
     '1' => '1AM',
     '2' => '2AM',
     '3' => '3AM',
     '4' => '4AM',
     '5' => '5AM',
     '6' => '6AM',
     '7' => '7AM',
     '8' => '8AM',
     '9' => '9AM',
     '10' => '10AM',
     '11' => '11AM',
     '12' => '12PM',
     '13' => '1PM',
     '14' => '2PM',
     '15' => '3PM',
     '16' => '4PM',
     '17' => '5PM',
     '18' => '6PM',
     '19' => '7PM',
     '20' => '8PM',
     '21' => '9PM',
     '22' => '10PM',
     '23' => '11PM',
);

foreach ($timings as $t) {
    
}
```

I would like to iterate the timings in a foreach loop, but before that, I would like to remove the timings between start time and end time.

Here my `$starttime` key is `5` and my `$endtime` key is `17`.

So I would like to remove `5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17` from the array and keep the remaining elements.

Can some tell me how to pop those elements out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Slice and Merge**

Just use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) like this:

```
$starttime = '5';
$endtime = '17';

$timings = array_merge(
              array_slice($timings, 0, intval($starttime)),
              array_slice($timings, intval($endtime) + 1)
           );
```

---

**Splice**

Another way which is simpler and a (insignificantly) more efficient is using [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php). Notice that it *returns the extracted array*, and *changes the original array*, so **don't** place the result inside $timings.

```
$starttime = '5';
$endtime = '17';

array_splice($timings,
             intval($starttime),
             (intval($endtime) - intval($starttime))
            );
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I tried your code. But its doing the exact opposite. It keeps `5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17` instead of removing from the array. Can you tell me how to fix that?

Comment: @Giri: I've edited the answer with another way of doing this. Maybe even a bit more efficient than using array_diff()

Comment: @ltay When I use `$starttime = '0'; $endtime = '23';` its still keeping only the last value. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Giri: Maybe you should add 1 to the second array offset. like this: array_slice($timings, (intval($endtime) + 1))

Comment: @Giri : I've added a better solution using array_splice.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that it is necessary to spell out that some techniques will destroy the original keys and other will preserve the original keys.

Codes: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Mss8J))

#### Loses Keys

```
function spliceKeys($timings, $starttime, $endtime) {
    array_splice($timings, $starttime, $endtime - $starttime);
    return $timings;
    
}

function sliceKeys($timings, $starttime, $endtime) {
    return array_merge(
              array_slice($timings, 0, $starttime),
              array_slice($timings, $endtime + 1)
           );
}
```

#### Keeps Keys

```
function diffKeys($timings, $starttime, $endtime) {
    return array_diff_key($timings, array_flip(range($starttime, $endtime)));
}

function skipKeys($timings, $starttime, $endtime) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($timings as $military => $timing) {
        if ($military >= $starttime && $military <= $endtime) {
            continue;
        }
        $result[$military] = $timing;
    }
    return $result;
}

function unsetKeys($timings, $starttime, $endtime) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($timings as $military => $timing) {
        if ($military >= $starttime && $military <= $endtime) {
            unset($timings[$military]);
        }
    }
    return $timings;
}
```